# Using a Parameter for Method Using Browser.execute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This block of code works. I would like to parameterise the value passed to `el.innText`.

```js
selectTemplateCheckBox() {
  const checkbox = this.templateCheckBox;
  const temp = templateName;
  browser.execute((selector) => {
    selector.find(el => el.innerText === 'AG-1743RAJ').previousElementSibling.querySelector('input').click();
  }, checkbox);
}
```

How can I parameterize the method for passing any value for `AG1743RAJ`?

```js
selectTemplateCheckBox(value) {
  const checkbox = this.templateCheckBox;
  const temp = templateName;
  browser.execute((selector) => {
    selector.find(el => el.innerText === value).previousElementSibling.querySelector('input').click();
  }, checkbox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
selectTemplateCheckBox(templateName) {
        const checkbox = this.templateCheckBox;
        const temp = templateName; 
        browser.execute((selector, temp) => {
            selector.find(el => el.innerText === `${temp}`).previousElementSibling.querySelector('input').click();
        }, checkbox, temp);  
    }
```